# How to calculate performance curve for each row of data

Tags: powerbi, calculation

I want to plot a performance curve for each row of data I have.

A simple version of what I want to do is plot the function with the equation as `Y= m*X+b`, where I have a table with `m` and `b` values and I want `Y` values for X = 1 to 10.

How is this calculated?

A `Y = mX + b` example can be seen in the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
WITH NUMBERS AS
(
SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))N(N)
),
Examples AS
(
SELECT m,b FROM (VALUES (1,2),(2,2))N(m,b)
)
SELECT 
     'Y = ' + CAST(Examples.m as varchar(10)) + 'X + ' + CAST(Examples.b as varchar(10)) AS Formula
    ,Numbers.N AS X
    , Numbers.N * Examples.m + Examples.b
FROM Examples
CROSS JOIN NUMBERS
```